# Can't move or remove files from Google Drive shared folder

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-shared-folder

A company I work with set up a shared folder in Google Drive for me to share files with them. In `Sharing settings` I see that the company `Is the owner` and I `Can edit`.

When I move files into the shared folder I cannot move or remove them anymore. When I select a file, right-click and choose `Remove` the file briefly disappears from view, Google Drive informs me that `One removed file is still accessible by collaborators` and then after a few seconds the file reappears.

Once I copy files to the shared folder I cannot move or remove them, so any mistake I make requires me to start over in a new folder. Is there a way around this? I know files and folders can have only a single owner, so no solution there. The only solutions I can think of are 1) asking the company to temporarily transfer ownership of the entire folder to me or 2) prepare the files I want to share in a different location and check them really, really carefully before I copy them to the shared folder. But since I share a lot of files I make mistakes quite often.

Comment: Is the folder on a Team Drive?

Answer (score 1):

Only owner can delete, move or rename the file. If you want to accomplish either of the aforementioned functions, please request the company to transfer folder/file ownership to you.
A person with edit access can only edit the contents of the file.

Comment: If the folder is not on a Team Drive , folder editors are able to remove files from it.

Comment: If a user has been added to a shared folder, they have permission to "Organise, add and edit files". It's not clear to me if "Organise" includes renaming and deleting.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, it is possible to move files within a shared directory. To do so, you first need to add the file to "My Drive". Then you can freely move the files within the shared directories.

This is discussed here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/drive/7Oyu_MFJoOc/-X_TZwNzCQAJ

Comment: If the folder is not on a Team Drive , folder editors are able to remove files from it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not authorized to do so or you can say that owner has not granted you permission for the same. Either you can request access permission from the owner of the file. Or you can take help of some professional solution that will move files from Google Drive Shared With Me folder also for you..

If you need any further guidance for the same, let me know I will guide you.